# Morphia - AggregationPipeline Calculated fields

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework, morphia

I'd like know how can I use multiply inside sum static method, in a AggregationPipeline with group by the same field using Morphia in Java.

Something like this, in Morphia:

```
   new BasicDBObject("totalSales",
                new BasicDBObject("$sum",
                        new BasicDBObject("$multiply",
                                new String[]{"$value", "$amount"})));
```

Is very similar at this question: [Calculated group-by fields in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25437823/calculated-group-by-fields-in-mongodb)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your **[aggregation framework](http://mongodb.github.io/morphia/1.0/guides/aggregation/)**, create a **[`projection`](http://mongodb.github.io/morphia/1.0/javadoc/org/mongodb/morphia/aggregation/AggregationPipeline.html#project(org.mongodb.morphia.aggregation.Projection...))** pipeline first that does the arithmetic calculations then use the new field in your **[`group`](http://mongodb.github.io/morphia/1.0/javadoc/org/mongodb/morphia/aggregation/AggregationPipelineImpl.html#group(java.lang.String,%20org.mongodb.morphia.aggregation.Group...))** pipeline, something like this:

```
Iterator<Foo> aggregate = datastore.createAggregation(Foo.class)
       .project(projection("_id").suppress(),
           projection("field1", "_id"),
           projection("field2"), projection("field3"),
           projection("sales", multiply(projection("value"), projection("amount"))))
      .group("field3", grouping("totalSales", sum("sales")));
```